# Detecting if user use the same device with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

Is there a way to detect if a user is using the same device/browser on a web page e.g. If the user enters the site in the morning with a laptop, the client-side sends a token to the server and if the user enters the site in the evening with the same laptop or device, the client-side must send the same token.

The possibility that comes to mind is saving a token in a cookie and getting it back later, but it is very unsafe.

Comment: What is unsafe about a cookie? You can make your cookies http-only and always use https, that's about as safe as it gets on the web. Indeed, anything else you dream up on your own will almost certainly be much more "unsafe".

Answer (score 1):

using a session cookie is the right way to do this.

HOWEVER if you are totally opposed to cookies, you could use localStorage with a random value

```
if (!localStorage.getItem("token")) {
  localStorage.setItem("token", Math.random());
}
// You can then make an ajax call with your token
```